# Bivariate restricted probit in R

Tags: r, probit, bivariate

I want to estimate a bivariate restricted probit model in R. In particular, I want to restrict the correlation between the models to 0.

Using the GJRM package & function, I was already able to estimate an unrestricted model, however, I have no clue how to implement restrictions there. The biprobit command from the mets package seems to support restrictions but the documentation is so bad that I am unable to follow how to implement the model in the first place.

In essence, I want a command that replicates Stata's biprobit command and permits application of the constraint command :)